# Why is Random faster than RandomReal?

Tags: performance-tuning, random

As of version 6, `Random[]` was superseded by `RandomReal[ ]` etc, but both still work perfectly well. Playing with some timing comparisons, I noticed that the original `Random[]` function appears to be faster, in single repeated drawings ...

ALSO, using the syntax `RandomReal[]` is faster than using `RandomReal[{0,1}]` ...

```
Table[RandomReal[{0,1}], {10^8}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[RandomReal[],      {10^8}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[Random[],          {10^8}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.1703,Null}
>
> {7.00452, Null}
>
> {4.99067, Null}

Similarly:

```
Do[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {10^7}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[RandomReal[],       {10^7}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[Random[],           {10^7}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.89869,Null}
>
> {2.56348, Null}
>
> {1.23561, Null}

Am I losing anything by not using the newer version, for basic Uniform(0,1) random draws like this?

EDIT: just to clarify ... the above refers to single calls on `RandomReal` / `Random`:  in my application, I am not able to call $10^7$ drawings in advance.

Comment: Typically it is more efficient to use a single call to `RandomReal` when generating multiple random numbers. How does the timing with `Random` compare with `RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^8]`?

Comment: `Random` uses an older and poorer PRNG algorithm.  Let me see if I can find some references.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard has an even better point in favor of `RandomReal`, but to follow up on my timing comment: `Do[Random[], {10^7}]` takes 1.3s; `RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7]` takes only 0.11s.

Comment: @MarcoB Absolutely - but in my particular application, I have to do single calls on `RandomReal` / `Random`, which is why I am looking at that comparison. Unfortunately, I can't generate them all in one go.

Comment: If relevant to your application, a description of the method used by `Random` (and of the new ones available to `RandomReal`) can be found in this tutorial: [Random Number Generation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bv6abp0zpm6q-jmlt5t) under the "Legacy" entry.

Comment: I seem to recall this being discussed before but my search skills and memory are failing me.  In my opinion since the new functions are optimized for generation en masse, and support multiple PRNG methods, it seems reasonable that they have a moderate overhead for individual calls.

Comment: At least somewhat related: [(75303)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75303/121)

Comment: If the underlying generator can be accessed, I wonder if it could be used, instead? In other words, run the setup code, ``
Random`InitializeGenerator``, and then run your code, followed by any teardown code. Just a thought; I'll try looking into it later.

Comment: If you need the random numbers one at a time, can't you just generate a few million of them in one call (`RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^8}]`) and index this list during your iterative process?

Comment: As @ Mr.Wizard notes, `Random` is using a weaker pseudoRNG under the hood. It's a linear congruential generator due to Marsaglia and Zaman if I recall correctly. Very good in its day, and fast. But it does suffer on certain types of correlation and lattice tests. As for internet references, there may be notes on MathGroup about this.

Answer (score 8):

The following two expressions are equivalent.

```
Table[RandomReal[], {10^8}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`{7.99593, Null}`

```
RandomReal[1., 10^8]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`{1.20604, Null}`

The second expression shows the advantage of `RandomReal` over `Random`.

#### Edit

Another consideration is the generator used. For example, when the Mersenne twister is specified, there is not so much difference.

```
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; 
Table[RandomReal[], {10^8}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`{8.16061, Null}`

```
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; 
Table[Random[], {10^8}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`{6.17236, Null}`

It may be the default generators are different and are contributing to the discrepancy you have noticed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the issue raised. The question relates to repeated individual calls on `RandomReal` ...  the application does not allow for generating them all in advance.

Comment: @wolfies. Well, you should consider the default generators may be different.

Comment: +1 for writing up the points made in the comments as a proper answer.  A caveat however: `Table` compiles and is much faster than `Do` which is what @wolfies actually cares about (single draws).  Also `Method -> "Legacy"` would probably be a better comparison.