# Why is Compile + RandomReal faster than random real?

Tags: performance-tuning, random, compile

In the process of playing around with `Compile`, I discovered something surprising. `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]` is a lot slower than `Compile[{}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]]`. What could account for this? I would have imagined the two would have similar speeds.

Here's exactly what I did. First a simple timer:

```
compareTiming[f1_, f2_, its_] :=
 With[{
   tf1 = First@AbsoluteTiming[Scan[f1, Range[its]]], 
   tf2 = First@AbsoluteTiming[Scan[f2, Range[its]]]},
  (tf2 - tf1)/Max@{tf1, tf2}
  ]
```

then:

```
In[115]:= randomReal3 = Compile[{}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]];
randomReal3U = Function[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]];
compareTiming[randomReal3[] &, randomReal3U, 10^6]

Out[117]= 0.131774
```

So the compiled form is 13% faster than the uncompiled form? But `RandomReal` is built-in and so I would have assumed is already implemented at the C level. What could be causing this?

I understand that I can, of course, generate a huge list of random vectors using `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^8, 3}]` or something but it would be nice to know why, when I need to get a large number of random vectors one at a time (absent something like storing $10^8$ of then and pulling randomly) the fastest way to do this is with a compiled version of a built-in function.

Comment: `Compile` does some argument checking during the compilation, which `RandomReal[]` might do at run-time.  Also, getting just `3` random numbers means the overhead is a higher proportion. With a sample size of `300000`, I get that the uncompiled version is faster.

Comment: I get a different results if I use `Do` instead of `Scan`, too.

Comment: The first comment makes me feel better. I was expecting the user-compiled version to be slower. The second is just fascinating. What do you think is causing that?

Comment: You mean `Do[i, {i, Range[10^6]}]`, yes? But I too get that it's much faster to use the `Do` imp.

Comment: I don't have a good idea....Yeah I was just going to fix that...It's not clear that different overheads explain which method is faster, though.

Comment: Also interesting is the fact that if you put a `Normalize` call in both functions you get no speed appreciable difference in speed.

Comment: Not to mention how fast `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^6, 3}]` is, which is the proper way to call it.

Comment: Of course, when you can. Sometimes the most straightforward thing is to sample a random vector at a time. My question is more: why are these two seemingly identical things different.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(75303)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75303/121) , [(105835)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105835/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 10^6 calls, the difference of `RandomReal` and the compiled version is 0.279 s on my machine. That makes a difference of 279 ns per call which is really next to nothing.

To show you, where the difference comes from, consider the following completely unrelated example

```
compareTiming[f1_, f2_, its_] := 
 With[{
   tf1 = First@RepeatedTiming[Do[f1[], {its}]], 
   tf2 = First@RepeatedTiming[Do[f2[], {its}]]},
   (tf2 - tf1)/Max[tf2, tf1]
 ]

testC = Compile[{}, 0];
test[] := 0;

compareTiming[testC, test, 10^6]
(* -0.2 *)
```

Here, the compiled version is slower. Now, we throw the *overhead* of another high-level function call in:

```
f[] := 0;
test[] := f[];

compareTiming[testC, test, 10^6]
(* 0.27 *)
```

This suggests that the difference in runtime does not come from *creating the random vector*, but it comes from the interpreter evaluating the function `f` (or `RandomReal`) as it has to access the `DownValues` of this function

Comment: The thing is, I'm intentionally not using any functions with `DownValues`. In fact the compiled form I supplied should be even slower for the fact that I wrapped it in a `Function` call so it's calling `Function` then `CompiledFunction` at each step. I agree it's unlikely that the issue comes from actually generating the vector. I assume those functions are the same.

Comment: But your definition of `randomReal3U` contains a `Function` as well. So this has to evaluate `Function` and then `RandomReal`. Have you tried what you get with `compareTiming[randomReal3[] &[] &, randomReal3U, 10^6]` which adds another layer of `Function` to the compiled call?