# Evaluation Time of RandomVariate Function

Tags: random, implementation-details

This question is about the runtime of the function `RandomVariate`.

Take a simple normalized Gaussian distribution G on the real line, I tried to generate N random variates of the distribution in two ways. The first way is simply to make a table:

```
Table[RandomVariate[G], {k, 1, N}]
```

The second way is to use the command:

```
RandomVariate[G, N]
```

From what I understood in the documentation, these two commands should be equivalent. However, when I checked the runtime, I found something surprising:

```
Timing[RandomVariate[G, 1]]                  =0.7348,
Timing[Table[RandomVariate[G],{k,1,N}]]      =0.7664

Timing[RandomVariate[G, 10]]                 =0.7289,
Timing[Table[RandomVariate[G],{k,1,N}]]      =8.1465

Timing[RandomVariate[G, 10^7]]               =2.4998
```

It seems to me that the runtime of the command involving `Table` scales with the number of variates, while the command without table barely does. This is pretty confusing to me. What property of the `RandomVariate[G, N]` command makes it so much faster than the naive table?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, avoiding `Table` would at the very least cut down on function call overhead. But in the specific case of random number generation, the setup of the `Random*` machinery is the more time consuming part; generating the variates is comparatively much easier.

This is mentioned in [this tutorial on Random number generation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html) as well:

> The two-argument interface provides a convenient way to obtain multiple random numbers at once. Even more importantly, there is a significant efficiency advantage to generating a large number of pseudorandom numbers at once.
>
> For statistical distributions, the speed advantage of generating many numbers at once can be even greater. In addition to the efficiency benefit inherited from the uniform number generators used, many statistical distributions also benefit from vectorized evaluation of elementary and special functions. For instance, WeibullDistribution benefits from vector evaluations of the elementary functions Power, Times, and Log.

So again asking `RandomVariate` for multiple values allows you to cut down on repetitive setup tasks. As an aside, you are better off using `AbsoluteTiming` rather than `Timing` when making such comparisons.

See also:

- [Why is Random faster than RandomReal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105835/27951)
- [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75304/27951) to [Can Mathematica's random number generation be improved?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75303/27951).